# Counting positions in a row oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I'm making bookstore database and in the table "Authors" I've got column where i'd like to count books written by author in the table "Books". Table "Books" has foreign key "id_author". I have no idea how to do it, it's something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Books WHERE id_author = "id of chosen author"
```

What to write in code in place of `"id of chosen author"`?

How to put it in a row in table "Author"?

Comment: You would just have to update it if the Author released a new book. You shouldn't really store dynamic data of this nature on the actual database, just extract it when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could join on the `authors` table and query by its columns (e.g., the first and last name):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   books b
JOIN   author a ON b.id_author = a.id
WHERE  a.firstname = 'John' AND a.lastname = 'Doe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application you have, the application might already have the author id. This means that you could just do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Books WHERE id_author = "id of author provided by application"
```

Although the difference is probably not large compared to Mureinik's answer, this can enhance your performance on large databases as you do not have to do the join between author and book table.

Answer (score 0):

Number of books by author:

```
select a.author, count(1)
from author a
join books b 
  on a.id = b.id_author
group by a.author
```